# Cakephp Simple Authentication tutorial page not redirecting to current page

Tags: cakephp

I am start going through the cakephp tutorials, I copy the source code exactly as shown in the tutorial.

I have done the Blog tutorial and all seems good, now I am onto the "Simple Authentication and Authorization Application" (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) tutorial, but are running into this issue.

1. The add page loads fine:

   ".../app/webroot/index.php/Users/add"
2. After hitting submit, it redirects me to this url (with the additional "Users" string) and with an error message.

   ".../app/webroot/index.php/Users/Users/add"

   ```
   Missing Method in UsersController

   Error: The action Users is not defined in controller UsersController

   Error: Create UsersController::Users() in file: app/Controller/UsersController.php.

   class UsersController extends AppController {


   public function Users() {

   }

   }
   ```

Let me know where I should start checking, Thanks.

---

AppController

```
    class AppController extends Controller {
        public $components = array(
            'Session',
            'Auth' => array(
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
                'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
            )
        );

        public function beforeFilter() {
            $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
       }

        public function isAuthorized($user) {
        // Admin can access every action
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
            return true;
        }

        // Default deny
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: `/app/webroot/index.php/Users/add`?
it could be a url rewriting issue: have you followed the url rewriting tutorial: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I still can't comment, I'll tell you here and edit this answer if I know it.

Show me your `AuthComponent` configuration in `AppController.php`.

EDIT:

Answer is in the comments below. :)

Comment: Please provide the login.ctp file or wherever the view file for login is.

Comment: copy exactly shown in tutorial: "http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html". Do a find for "<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>" and that section of code is what i have for my login.ctp

Comment: Try with this tutorial, it's really great: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM. And one more thing... Check for mod_rewrite. Is it working?

Comment: finally got mod_rewrite working, then I found this : **http://www.chriscassell.net/log/2006/07/27/how_to_install_.html** This work around got it working, I think, only through the alias address though, still a no go for actual long address "**.../app/webroot/index.php/Users/add**". Will try the tutorial. thanks.